# Cast list to list: index out of range error

Tags: c#, .net, list, casting

I have declared following structures:

```
List<List<Service.Field>> out = new List<List<Service.Field>>();
List<List<Service.Field>> tempOut = new List<List<Service.Field>>();
tempOut.Add(method.ReturnFields);
out.AddRange(tempOut);
```

When i do:

```
 out = out.OrderByDescending(a => (DateTime)a[1].Value).ToList();
```

I get an error:

> Exception in process (processName) Exeption Type:
>   System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException, Exeption Message: Index was out of
>   range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
>   Parameter name: index,

Before this action i check and out.OrderByDescending(a => (DateTime)a[1].Value) is not null.

Any idea why casting is returning this message?

Comment: maybe on of sub Lists in your `out` collection hasn't any items, and it works fine for first item, but fail for another item?

Comment: you have to check if a have 2 item or more a is not null not mean have more then item, a[1] you check the second item

Comment: Here is a sample fiddle where it doesn't work - http://dotnetfiddle.net/sg15ff because third one item hasn't any subitimes in it.

Comment: @SergeyLitvinov thank you! You are right! Now i know where the problem is. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Only when you are calling `ToList` your order query is executed. Before that call this is just a `IQueryable` object. And since apparently not all of the lists in `out` have two elements you are getting the exception after the `ToList` call. To handle this you need to check for the existence of element `a[1]`. For example:

```
out1 = out1.OrderByDescending(a => (a.Count >= 1) ? (DateTime)a[1].Value : DateTime.MinValue).ToList();
```

Side note. `out` is reserved in C#, are you sure your code compiles?

Comment: Yes it is compiled.
I changed names in text editor because it is my comercial code and I cannot show real data :)
Thank you for fast response!